# Image Segmentation with a challenging background

Tags: python, classification, neural-network, scikit-learn, image-classification

I'm working on an animal classification problem, with the data extracted from a video feed. The recording was made in a pen, so the problem is quite challenging with a dark background and many shadows: [image]

Initially I tried scikit-image, but then someone helped me with an advanced tool called crf-rnn (http://crfasrnn.torr.vision/) that does a great job segmenting and labelling objects in an image. I did the following:

```
import caffe
net = caffe.Segmenter(MODEL_FILE, PRETRAINED)
IMAGE_FILE = '0045_crop2.png'
input_image = caffe.io.load_image(IMAGE_FILE)
from PIL import Image as PILImage
image = PILImage.fromarray(np.uint8(input_image))
image = np.array(image)
mean_vec = [np.mean(image[:,:,vals]) for vals in range(image.shape[2])]
im = image[:, :, ::-1]
im = im - reshaped_mean_vec
cur_h, cur_w, cur_c = im.shape
pad_h = 750 - cur_h
pad_w = 750 - cur_w
print(pad_h, pad_w, "999")
im = np.pad(im, pad_width=((0, max(pad_h,0)), (0, max(pad_w,0)), (0, 0)), mode = 'constant', constant_values = 255)
segmentation = net.predict([im])
segmentation2 = segmentation[0:cur_h, 0:cur_w]
```

The resulting image segmentation is rather poor (although two cows are recognized correctly):
[image]

I use a trained crf-rnn (MODEL_FILE, PRETRAINED), which works well for other problems, but this one is harder. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to pre-process this sort of image to extract the shape of most cows.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/202901/2921

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be appreciated if you could explain precisely what your goal is:

1. you want to identify what animal is in your picture ?
2. you want to count the number of animals ?
3. you want to get the position of each animal in the picture ?

In any case, I know that you can get some already trained neural nets from google or anywhere else. This neural net can be used with caffe as it is the case in this google deepdream stuff on github (look at ):

https://github.com/google/deepdream/blob/master/dream.ipynb

Then, if you want to highlight or identify the positions of your animals, you'll find this article inspiring:

http://www.matthewzeiler.com/pubs/cvpr2010/cvpr2010.pdf

It explain how to reverse convolutional networks to identify what part of your image helped to recognize what is inside. The found projection get you something similar to your second picture (called a mask), but depending on the neural net you use, you can get better results.

Comment: 'what your goal is':  point 2+3; he problem is that the background in hard to extract, as there are a lot of shadows and many cows are of a similar color

Comment: Well, your image still have some good edges. You can try using some edge detection algorithm to accentuate the objects limits: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection.
But once again, I think the current network your working with is just not good enough for this case. Did you try some basic preprocessing like contrast or spectral regularization ?

Comment: Do you mean like this: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.exposure.html#skimage.exposure.equalize_hist

Comment: I think edge-based algorithms are more adapted since neural networks and image recognition are mostly based on edges (and not colors). So you should try amplifying the edges on your image.

Comment: I've had a bit of success with histogram equalization to increase contrast, but otherwise not sure how to continue. What can I do to maximize the effect of a segmentation algorithm?

Comment: Needless to say, I've tried the scikit-image built-in algorithms like pixel-level labeling, but crf-rnn outperforms them

Comment: To be even more specific, I'm not sure how to handle the fact that object and background are of (roughly) the same color

Comment: I don't know any specific algorithm to point you to. But the idea would be to extract edges, and use an algorithm to "close" them (the cow that are not detected have only a few parts of their edge that merge with the background). I work with OpenCV before and remember having working with such algorithms, they usually play with gaussian filters.

Comment: But anyway, using neural net like the crf-rnn should avoid this kind of exercise since you only need to recognize a part of the cow, not its entire boundary. Try again increasing the contrast (try to see with your own appreciation if this helps differentiating the cows).

Comment: 'recognize a part of the cow, not its entire boundary' - not exactly, I need the full cow as I'll need in the next step to find what it's doing